# image from java serverlet to another jsp

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, forms, jsp

My problem is  when i retrieve some strings from mydemo.java in my GET method of index.jsp with this form :

```
 <form method="get" action ="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/myserverlet?">

 name:   <input type = "text"  name = "nome" placeholder = "name" value="${name}" ><br><br>
  etc .... ...
```

he takes these values from /myserverlet and returns an image from concatenated strings like following :

```
 String v_card = String.format("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s", header_info,name, company, tel,mail,footer);
```

That's ok , but , my problem is: how can i pass this image that he retrieves  from /servelet to another jsp page and not index.jsp ? should i do something in "myfile2.jsp"?

Comment: why don't you put your image files in some resource folder and have direct link using context from that folder

Comment: because i create my image dynamically with a method like :   `private byte[] getQRCodeImage(String text, int width, int height) `   and then in getmethod i have:   `outputstream.write(getQRCodeImage(v_card,200,200)`  v_card is my concatenate string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="v_card" value="${v_card}">
```

And then you can pass that using

```
session.setAttribute("v_card", v_card);
```

Now as long as your session is active you can retrieve the value in any jsp

```
String v_card = session.getAttribute("v_card");
```

After that you can assign this value to image tag to display the image

Comment: see if i got it . So, i added <input etc. in my index.jsp and i have't changed my action in my form, it still "${pageContext.request.contextPath }/myserverlet?" Then, in mydemo.java i have :  `HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       
       session.setAttribute("v_card", v_card);`    then , in myfile2.jsp i retrieved image like  `<img src =  "/myserverlet?${v_card}"`  . Is it right ?

Comment: yes it works i look the qr image but my page it still works in index.jsp i think, and not in myfile2.jsp . this is my output (i tried with name data like aaaaaa for example) :  `http://localhost:8080/prQrCode/myserverlet?v_card=BEGIN%3AVCARD%0D%0AN%3Aaaaaaaaaaaa%0D%0AORG%3A%0D%0ATEL%3A%0D%0AEMAIL%3A%0D%0AEND%3AVCARD&nome=aaaaaaaaaaa&company=&tel=&mail=`

Comment: and also in url like you see , i've got this response 2 times .

Comment: so will you able to get image ?

Comment: It always open me up a new page when gives me the output . the output is not in myfile2.jsp page as i would like

Comment: did you tried assigning this url to image source instead of opening in url ?

Comment: i tried in this way : in myfile2.jsp : `<img src="/myfile2.jsp?v_card=${v_card}">` in mydemo.java i have `HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("v_card", v_card);
       session.getAttribute("v_card");`    and in my index.jsp i have: `<form method=get action ="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/myserverlet?">`

Comment: you need to do something like this in myfile2.jsp <img src="data:image/png;base64,[v_card]">

Comment: ok now it works!! i passed a base64 string with httpsession like you said to me! thank you so much eshu!